# Get a list of PDB ids from a list of sequence protein number?

Tags: python, pdb

I am working on a project about phosphorylation, and I am creating a database of some proteins. I have a list of protein accession ids for which I need to get the corresponding PDB file for each one to map it to PSM matrix. I want to get the PDB file using Python or BioPython tools. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a list of protein ids, and I want to retrieve PDB code for each one! I made the protein ids database with the phosphorylation cite for each position. However, I need PDB code because I want to map it to PSM matrix. I have no idea how to retrieve PDB code! Thanks again

Comment: Please include a few IDs and the expected outcome, i.e. ID: P26378 should map to PDB: 1FXL, etc. If you just need to do it a few times, you could use the UniProt web interface, just upload a bunch of identifiers and get the corresponding PDB IDs. https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your reply. I am currently using this website to map protein accession ids to  PDB. However, I want to do it by the code because I have a big list of protein ids. I want to get PDB by code so I can map it to PSSM to get the structure of the proteins. I want to do it in the one piece of code,not separately! Again Thanks for your kind and helpful reply!

Answer (score 2):

A typical Uniprot URL would look like the example here:

https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=ID:P26378&format=tab&columns=id%2Cdatabase(PDB)

The response will be:

> Entry Cross-reference (PDB)
>
> P26378    1FXL;1G2E;

We want our query to include the protein ID, the output format should be tab separated and the only contain the columns `id` and `database (PDB)`.

To get the PDB IDs you would need to split the response, take the last line, split this line after each tab and split it again after each semi-colon.

Using Python's Requests library the whole code would be.

```
import requests
import time

uniprot_ids = ['P26378', 'O35433', 'Q02910']
url = 'https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/'

protein_to_pdb = {}
for protein in uniprot_ids:
    params = {
        'format': 'tab',
        'query': 'ID:{}'.format(protein),
        'columns': 'id,database(PDB)'
    }
    contact = ""  # Please set your email address here.
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Python {}'.format(contact)}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    protein_to_pdb[protein] = str(r.text).splitlines()[-1].split('\t')[-1].split(';')
    protein_to_pdb[protein].pop(-1)
    time.sleep(1)  # be respectful and don't overwhelm the server with requests

print(protein_to_pdb)
```

---

- To accelerate things, you could store your `protein_to_pdb` dict in a file and only retrieve the new ones
- Checking if the returned ID matches your input ID is always a good idea

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your answer and your time with me. Please I want to read a file which has a list of protein ids as df ,and retrieve all PDB codes for each one. I am trying to edit on your code by using :"df.iloc[i,1] = str(r.text).splitlines()[-1].split('\t')[-1].split(';')" ,but there is an error which is "list index out of range". Please can you  help me with that?

Comment: I did it by using :"df.iloc[i,1] = r" instead of using a list,and I get a file with all protein ids and PDB codes. Is that correct? Or I am missing something! Thank you so much for your answer; it is really helping me a lot. I really appreciate it .

Comment: Try a more simple example, just copy a few ids in the list and see if it works. Without seeing your dataframe it is hard to guess where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mapping between UniProt and PDB entries from the [SIFTS project](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/docs/sifts/).
The `uniprot_pdb.csv` file there has UniProt accession names followed by a semicolon-separated list of PDB four letter codes.